# How can I make a simulation rendered depth image look like a stereo matching created depth image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

For a AI project I am collecting images from a simulated environment and a real environment. In both scenarios there is a grayscale depth image generated. However the simulated environment generates perfect depth images which are not representative of the real world. This is why I want to artificially make the depth image of the simulation look like the one from the real world.

I am looking for some functions in for example opencv to generate noise to make the simulated image look like the real world. I already tried opencv filter2D which improved the image a bit. But I am looking for some other functions which work better.

The real world depth image is generated using a ZED2 stereo vision camera.

Note that these images are not from the same situation. However they both have threes so they should give a bit the idea.

Simulated image:

[image]

real world image:

[image]

Thanks

Sieuwe

Comment: to get a real simulation you will need to know how the ZED2 works in detail and what kind of "tricks" it uses. But as a guess I would say you might get a similar image by 1. rendering the depth to a smaller resolution image, 2. removing some depth value pixels randomly (set to 0?), 3. using a bigger median filter, 4. upscale to your target resolution

Comment: render two color views of your scene (stereo pair), then throw that into a block matching algorithm.

Comment: Christoph Rackwitz has the right idea here. The problem with trying to add noise to a perfect depth map to recreate real life is that the mistakes that the camera is making are non-random. For example, if you have a wall with a flat color and no visual landmarks, then it will have a lot of trouble finding depth. The easiest way to recreate that is to try to estimate depth from two renders of the scene from two virtual cameras.

Answer (score 0):

You can try synthesizing the 2d images and then reconstruct the depth map with noises. Below are detailed steps:

1. Assume 1 camera matrix with random extrinsic parameters and then create another camera matrix with similar pose to make it look like stereo paired cameras.
2. Project the simulated depth map to 2d image using these 2 camera poses to generate stereo pairs of images.
3. Add random noises in the images to introduce noise in feature point correspondences
4. Given 2 views of same scene, estimate the depth map which will contain real world noises.